# Wrong files added to WAR package using Gradle

Tags: java, war, gradle

I'm using Gradle 1.5 and I'm trying to adapt the [WAR plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) to an Eclipse dynamic project.

When the WAR is exported by eclipse it has the `xhtml` files straight on the root of the war file, and I managed to do that with Gradle.

But on my Gradle exported war I have the `xhtml` files duplicated inside `WEB-INF/classes` along with my `.class` files

I only want to have my `.class` files in that folder, but I haven't found a way to do it

Here's the relevant part of my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'

webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}

eclipse {
    // my eclipse plugin config..
}

dependencies {
    // my dependencies config.
}
```

The only customization I have done to the war plugin was change the `webAppDirName` to point to my `WebContent` folder.

Does anyone know how to define what goes inside the `WEB-INF/classes` directory? I can't seem to get the hang of it.

---

**EDIT**
I have managed to remove the `.xhtml` duplicates by referring the resources to my `bin` directory like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'bin'
        }
    }
}
```

But I still have wrong files in my `WEB-INF`.

I have even this structure `WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF`. I don't know why these folders are being added to my `classes` directory, since they don't exist in my `bin`

I want the classes in my `bin` to be in `WEB-INF/classes`
and the static resources in my `WebContent` to be in the root of the WAR file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, what goes into `WEB-INF/classes` is the output of the `main` source set (compiled classes and processed resources). Your build script declares an additional source directory (`src`), and keeps the default resource directory. Do you have any files under `src/main/java` or `src/main/resources`?

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how I can prevent the extra folders from being added to my `classes` dir? Is there any more information you need?

Comment: I don't know what your source directory structure is. Again, do you have any files under `src/main/java` or `src/main/resources`? Have you tried to override the defaults (e.g. `srcDirs = ['src']`), rather than adding additional directories?

Comment: No my files are directly under `src` there is no `main/java` structure. Can you edit your answer to show me an example of an override please?

Comment: I edited the entries from `resources{ srcDir 'bin' }` to `resources{ srcDirs = ['bin'] }` should that make *only* the files in the `bin` dir be copied?

Comment: In terms of resources, the answer is yes. You should do the same for `sourceSets.main.java`.

Comment: That seems to have solved it. I didn't know that using `srcDir` I was adding one, really my bad. Thanks a lot, Peter!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses the `bin` folder as its output folder, so there's a possibility, that your files get mixed up this way.