# WAR File contains static resources twice after Gradle WAR build

Tags: java, spring, gradle

In the past, the static resources for the web application were always under `src/main/webapp`.

Recently, `Spring Initializr` created a new project layout for me and thus found that the resources should be under `src/main/resources/static`. I assume this is the new standard.
Due to this change, the projects now also run immediately under IntelliJ and for Eclipse I have this adaptation in the `build.gradle` file:

```
project.webAppDirName = 'src/main/resources/static'

eclipse {
    wtp {
        component {
            contextPath = '/'
            deployName = 'myapp'
        }
        facet {
            //facet name: 'jst.web', version: '3.1'
            file {
                whenMerged {
                    facets.each { f ->
                        if (f.name == 'jst.web') {
                            f.version = '3.1'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have built a WAR today, and had to realize that the static resources are double in it.

A certain magic (automatism) takes place.

Something copies my static resources into the root of the WAR as it was when they were under `webapp`. The same resources can also be found under `WEB-INF/classes/static`

I assume the static resources are at the right place in the root of the WAR. What is the correct way in `Gradle` to avoid the resources under `WEB-INF/classes/static`?

Answer (score 0):

The content from `src/main/resources` is copied to `WEB-INF/classes` by default. Setting project.webAppDirName creates an additional `sourceSet` that is copied to the (root folder of the) `war` file.

To exclude certain files from the default copy operation, you can exclude files from the `sourceSet` like this:

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude('**/static/**')
}
```

This is documented here:

[How to exclude src/main/resources files from the final WAR?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-src-main-resources-files-from-the-final-war/11895/2)
[How to Exclude directory and its contents in gradle war](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35995668/7821823)
[How can I exlude files from WAR when using WAR plugin against default or webAppDirName location](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-exlude-files-from-war-when-using-war-plugin-against-default-or-webappdirname-location/7366/10)
[Wrong files added to WAR package using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301011/7821823)